# Build a lookup query in Excel using named ranges stored in a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vlookup, named-ranges

I have a spreadsheet which has a lot of named ranges, each of which is a table. I want to be able to run a lookup that will retrieve a value from any of the tables. I want to be able to store the name of the named range in a cell.

I tried:

```
=HLOOKUP(B14,B6,(B22+1),FALSE)
```

B14 was the value I wanted to look up. B6 stored the name of the named range, and using data validation can only contain the name of a named range. B22 stored the number of rows in the table and of course the +1 just stops the lookup starting in the header row.

The problem is that Excel's lookup syntax thinks that I am typing the cell range for the look-up; that B6 is the range.

I found a way to add a list of all the named ranges defined in the spreadsheet together with the range of cells using the Formulas/Defined Names/Use In Formula. I thought that I could use this as a nested lookup along the lines of

```
=vlookup(B6,Sheet1!$A$1,$B$77,2,FALSE)
```

but although this by itself returns the correct value, it does so as if it is text. I notice that there is an = at the beginning of the string and wonder if I can detach this (`MID` function?), then it might be able to be recognised as a range of cells to look up. The problem with the `MID` function though is that you have to know the number of characters in the string and some will have more characters than others - single vs double letters for columns and units vs tens vs hundreds for rows

So I'm stuck and in need of help: any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is difficult to follow all that you are trying to do without seeing it. This article may help you - [Use the VLOOKUP Function Across Multiple Tables](http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/ms-office/excel/Use_The_VLOOKUP_Function_Across_Multiple_Tables.htm).

Answer (score 3):

Hard to tell exactly what you're looking for without a screenshot but this might work for you. It's a dynamic `VLOOKUP` formula that takes table names and column names as inputs.

Here's the formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(F14,INDIRECT(F15),MATCH(F16,INDIRECT(F15&"[#Headers]"),0),0)
```

It uses `INDIRECT` to refer to your named ranges, and `MATCH` to work out which column you need to enter in your `VLOOKUP`.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks Andi. I usually spend hours with nested if statements to get results like this but I have recently started using named ranges after going on a course, but this makes them so much more valuable. This one was In my case I have not needed the Match function (which is also new to me).

Comment: Many thanks Andi. I usually spend hours with nested if statements to get results like this but I have recently started using named ranges after going on a course, but this makes them so much more valuable. This one was so much worse as I was working with 76 look-ups, which I even if it didn't break Excels nested limit would be nightmare when it came to hunt the missing bracket! In my case I have not needed the Match function (which is also new to me) as I had another expression which determined the number of rows down in the expression. Once again I cannot thank you enough for your help. :D